# What is the difference between gremlin in neptune to azure selecting a single vertex?

Tags: azure, gremlin, amazon-neptune

we switched our database from azure to neptune. In azure you could select one vertex and the gremlinquery returned the id, the label and all properties of this vertex. If you do the same on neptune, just the id and the label is returned. How can I get neptune to return the id, the label and all properties of a vertex? Is there a option you can choose in the neptune configuration? If there is no option, which query I have to execute to get the id, the label and all properties of a vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference might have to do with a number of things. First thing that comes to mind is that if you went from CosmosDB to Neptune you might be using bytecode based traversals in which case they don't return properties (just references which means `id` and `label` as you are seeing). If you didn't switch then it's possible that Neptune may be more aligned with TinkerPop in terms of serialization semantics which calls for [references only in newer versions](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/upgrade/#_referenceelementstrategy).

Either way, it's considered a best practice to only return the data that you need in the form you want it, rather than a graph element with all properties. The reasoning is similar to why you wouldn't do `SELECT * FROM table` in SQL - you would specify the column names.

Comment: Okay, which query I have to use to get the result from azure in neptune? The id, the label and all properties in one result?